# Using a DataSource in WSO2 BAM 2.0

Tags: mysql, hive, wso2, wso2-bam

I´d like to use a MySQL database to store the results of Hive analytics scripts in BAM 2.0.1. Taking a look at the supplied examples, I can see that I have to pass connection information using a number of properties (mapred.jdbc.*).

Is there a way to use a Carbon datasource instead of direct jdbc connections ? My main concern is the use of cleartext passwords in a script, a big blocker in security-concerned organizations.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it is possible. You can use wso2.carbon.datasource.name parameter to pass the name of the carbon datasource.

Comment: Using this property did the trick. My example table looks like that:

Comment: would be great if you can make this repsonse as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Using passwords is required as server-to-server authentication is not properly implemented in Carbon framework yet. But in recent future we hope to remove this issue with an improvement to BAM.

Answer (score 0):

Using the property as chamibuddhika described did the trick. The table declaration below shows a complete example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BatchSummaryByWeek(
execYear SMALLINT,
execWeek SMALLINT,
job_name STRING,
exit_code INT,
totalExecutions INT,
avgElapsed FLOAT,
maxElapsed INT,
minElapsed INT
) 
STORED BY 
'org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.JDBCStorageHandler' 
TBLPROPERTIES ( 
'wso2.carbon.datasource.name' = 'MYSQL_BAM',
'hive.jdbc.update.on.duplicate' = 'true' , 
'hive.jdbc.primary.key.fields' = 'execYear,execWeek,job_name,exit_code' , 
'hive.jdbc.table.create.query' = 'CREATE TABLE BatchSummaryByWeek(execYear INTEGER, execWeek SMALLINT,job_name VARCHAR(250), exit_code INT,totalExecutions INT, avgElapsed FLOAT, maxElapsed INT,minElapsed INT)' );
```